# how do I select a part of a column with condition in R?

Tags: r

```
  select(dateRep, cases, countriesAndTerritories)%>%
  separate(col= dateRep,
           into = c("day","month","year"),
           sep = "/")%>%
  filter(year==2020)%>%
  filter(countriesAndTerritories %in% c("Germany","Spain","France","United_States_of_America","United_Kingdom"))%>%
  group_by(countriesAndTerritories, month)%>%
  summarize(monthly_cases = sum(cases))%>%
  mutate(Cumulative_cases = cumsum(monthly_cases))%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  mutate(countriesAndTerritories = fct_reorder2(countriesAndTerritories,month,Cumulative_cases))
  

#write.csv(covid_data_tbl, "covid3.csv")
#visulization
covid_data_tbl%>%
  ggplot(aes(month)) +
  
  geom_line(aes(y=Cumulative_cases_of_germany)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Cumulative_cases_of_france))
```

I wanted to plot the cumulative sum of COVID cases for each country. Before visualization, my data looks like this. How can I select only cumulative cases of Germany? [image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example along with expected output. We cannot copy data from an image. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use cumsum() function to get the cumulative sum.